# Is NAT iptables available in 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, iptables

I have an Ubuntu 11.04. I wanted to play around with iptables rules. But I don't see it installed. When I did:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -F chain
```

This is what it returned:

```
iptables v1.4.10: can't initialize iptables table `-nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

So is nat table not available?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's available. I think that you've ran the command with a dash in fron of the table name.

Comment: Ooops!! u are right! Guess I can delete this post now :)